# SQL — Union two tables but Join on one of the columns

Tags: sql, join, union

I have two tables that look like this:

Table 1:

```
name | event | country
```

Table 2:

```
name | event
```

There are no overlapping rows between Table 1 and Table 2, because of the 'event' column. I wanted to union Table 1 with Table 2 since there are no overlaps, but I also want to fill in 'country' for Table 2 using the values from Table 1, with 'name' as the Join key. How do I do this?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the relation of the 2 tables is `1:1` you can use `UNION ALL` for `table1` and a query that joins (with a left join just in case there are no matches) `table2` to `table1` to retrieve the value of the column `country`:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*, t1.country 
from table2 t2 left join table1 t1
on t1.name = t2.name
```

or with a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.* from table1 t1
union all
select t2.*, (select t1.country from table1 t1 where t1.name = t2.name)
from table2 t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   SELECT * FROM TABLE1 t1
   UNION
   Select t2.*, t1.country from table2 t2 
   Join table1 t1 on t2.name=t1.name
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a full join:

```
select *
from table1 t1 full join
     table2 t2
     using (name, event);
```

If your database doesn't support `full join`, you can use:

```
select t1.name, t1.event, t1.country
from table1 t1
union all
select t2.name, t2.event, null
from table2 t2
where not exists (select 1 from table1 t1 where t1.name = t2.name and t1.event = t2.event);
```